# Can not change the font style of a view using Typeface.createFromFile()

Tags: android, android-studio

I must use `Typeface.createFromFile()` to use a location of a font inside the user's memopry, so the font file will be selected by user and then used to change the font of a view.  I cannot use `Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"FileAssets");` because the font file is dynamic and can be selected by the user.  The code below is the sample code for changing a font style of a textview, but it doesn't work.  How can I handle it?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/testfont/","font1.ttf");
        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                Typeface tb = Typeface.createFromFile(file.getPath());
                tv.setTypeface(tb);
            }
            catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.d("TED", "Unable to create a font from " + file.getName());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So am thinking, you could get the absolute path of the font when a user first selects it and store it somewhere like in preferences or database; then you won't have to worry about path issues

Comment: I have changed it to this but still it does not work
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/testfont/", "font.ttf"));

Answer (score 1):

```
File file = new File("sdcard/testfont.font.ttf");
```

This is not a valid path. Use appropriate methods to construct a path to your font file on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

If, while you are experimenting with Android, you are putting the font as a `testfont.font.ttf` file in the root of external storage, use:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "testfont.font.ttf"));
```

Note that you will need to hold the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to access this location, and that in turn will require you to implement [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) if your `targetSdkVersion` is set to 23 or higher.

Comment: @user3351571: [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Fonts/FontSampler) that demonstrates using custom fonts. If you are crashing, check your Java stack trace for instructions. If you are not crashing, but the font does not appear to be changing, try a different font, as if Android cannot decode a font properly, it seems to just quietly fail, rather than throw an exception.

Comment: this code is not working , I copy the same name file in the same location , but it is not working !
if (font.exists()) {
      tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.file);
      face=Typeface.createFromFile(font);
      
      tv.setTypeface(face);
    }
    else {
      findViewById(R.id.filerow).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  }
}